# How to add second css rule to javascript .css function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how is it possible to add a second css rule to this function.
As an example i want to change the fontcolor too.

```
$("#Testtable tr td").filter(function () 
        {
        var x = "xyz";
        return $(this).text() === x;
        }).closest('tr').css("background-color", "white");
```

Comment: Use an object...`.css({ 'background-color': white, 'color': 'blue' });`

Comment: One jQuery documentation says more than a thousand words... http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @UweB Well there are literally "more than thousand" words on that page. and one may not be in a position to scan through all of them..just saying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery docs on `.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties):

You can simple pass a object to `.css`:

```
$('#myElement').css({
    "background-color": "#ffe",
    "border-left": "5px solid #ccc"
});
```

The object can contain as many css properties as you wish / need.

Alternatively, you *could* chain `.css()` calls, but that would be inefficient, harder to maintain, and more code to achieve the same as a object (So, this is how *not* to do it):

```
.css("background-color", "#ffe",).css("border-left", "5px solid #ccc");
```

Fun fact:

jQuery recognizes both `background-color` and `backgroundColor`. The one with a hyphen *has* to be contained in quotes:

```
{"background-color":"white"}
```

While for the latter one, quotes are optional when using it in the object:

```
{backgroundColor:"white"}
```

However, for the sake of consistency, I'd say: Always use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use like this..

```
$("#Testtable tr td").filter(function () 
        {
        var x = "xyz";
        return $(this).text() === x;
        }).closest('tr').css({
            "background-color" :  "white",
            "display" : "block"
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to just use `.addClass` if you are adding multiple CSS properties to an element, as this is more maintainable and readable.

However, to answer your question, pass the `.css` method an object literal:

```
.css({
   'background-color' : 'white',
   color : 'yellow'
});
```

Any CSS properties with a hyphen need to be in quotes.